# Как преобразовать HtmlCollection в List?

Tags: c#

В WebBrowser запускаю js-скрипт

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('notification-item  feed-ORDER');
```

В items содержится `HtmlCollection`. Как его преобразовать в список `List`? Например `items[i].innerHTML` добавить в список?

Comment: `items.Cast<...>().ToList()`

Comment: @АндрейNOP так не работает